# How to display data within a drawn polygon

Tags: mapbox, ndvi

I am using mapbox as my base layer and would like to implement a functionality as shown in this gif below, where if i draw a polygon , it reads from my geotiff file and display NDVI data. I would like to color code pixels appropriately ranging from red to green based on NDVI value

Can someone point me to right direction please.

[image]

Comment: you could start with this: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/using-box-queryrenderedfeatures/